# MDT 2010 Deployment Workbench remote access

Tags: deployment, mdt-2010, remote-access

Is it possible to install the Deployment Workbench console on a workstation to manage an MDT server on the LAN?  I don't want to have to install the whole of MDT to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the MDT Workbench on a workstation and then connect to a remote Deployment Share if that is what you're asking. You will have to install WAIK/PowerShell on the workstation though.

Comment: I'm looking for the absolute minimum installation required to do this.